# Integrating a function bottom to top vs top to bottom.

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, uniform-distribution

Y is a uniform distribution on [0,1]
Let $U=Y_1+Y_2$ Find the Cdf of U.

For $1\leq u\leq2$
we can describe cdf of U as the proportional volume of the shaded area below to 1, for every u.

The example goes on to find the shaded area by 1-A where $A=\int_{u-1}^{1} {\int_{u-y_1}^{1} 1 dy_2} dy_1$.

[image]

This makes sense, but when I tried calculating the shaded region using 2 other methods, I got different answers. My issues may not just be with the random variable part but with the double integration part too.

**Method 1:**

Instead of calculating the area of A, I calculated the area of the red shaded region, which by the (-1) gradient of $y_2=-y_1 +u$ should by the same.[image]

Then the integral becomes: $\int_{u-1}^{1} \int_{u-1}^{u-y_1} 1 dy_2 dy_1$ but this evaluates to something different than $A=\int_{u-1}^{1} {\int_{u-y_1}^{1} 1 dy_2} dy_1$. Why is this?

**Method 2:**

Just integrating the $u=y_1+y_2$ line from $0\leq y_1\leq<1$ and then subtracting from it the red triangle of area $(u-1)^2$

[image]

I know the fact that the function we're integrating =1 gives us a lot of leniency in terms of evaluating the problem as simple prisms, but if we were technical here, does the fact that the pdf of Y is discontinuous at 1 mean that we can't integrate the interval containing 1? ie [0,u] where u>1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three of your methods should give the same answer  $\dfrac{(2-u)^2}{2}$

- **Method 0:** $$\int_{u-1}^{1} {\int_{u-y_1}^{1} 1 \,dy_2} \,dy_1= \int_{u-1}^{1} {(1-u+y_1)} \,dy_1 \\= \frac{(2-u)^2}{2}$$
- **Method 1:** $$\int_{u-1}^{1} \int_{u-1}^{u-y_1}  1 \,dy_2 \,dy_1= \int_{u-1}^{1} {(1-y_1)} \,dy_1 \\= \frac{(2-u)^2}{2}$$
- **Method 2:** $$1 - \left(\int_{0}^{1} {(u-y_1)} \,dy_1  -  \int_{0}^{u-1} {(u-y_1-1)} \,dy_1  \right) =1-\left(\left(u-\frac12\right) -\frac{(u-1)^2}{2}\right) \\= \frac{(2-u)^2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your math. I evaluated both method 1's integrals and they both come up the same.

Regarding method 2, since the integral is over a continuous graph in $0\le y \le 1$, there is no difference whether you add the zero-width point value or not. It only matters if there is a Dirac delta function added at that point.